# SQL запрос на получение id

Tags: sql

Задача такова, получить ID по наименованию игрока
структура таблицы

`(id, string(name), idvk, idtelegram, iddiscord)`

Вот мой запрос, но он не работает:

`` SELECT `username` FROM `dbuser` WHERE `username` = "UserTest" AND `id`; ``

Comment: Такое впечатление, что вы даже не пытались разобраться в структуре `SQL` запросов

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM dbuser WHERE username = 'UserTest'
```